# How to assign a value to an element in 2D vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

How I can assign a number to specific element of 2D vector without modifying other elements in tha row?

I am trying to assign a value to an element in a 2D vector but the value is assigned to whole row in the vector.

```
void prinVec2D(vector<vector<int> > & A) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << A[i][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

vector<vector<int> > generateMatrix(int A) {
    vector<vector<int> > ans(A, vector<int> (A, 0));
    ans[1][1] = 1;
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    int A = 4;
    vector<vector<int> > abc(A, vector<int>(A, 0));
    abc = generateMatrix(A);
    prinVec2D(abc);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected:

0 0 0 0 \n
0 1 0 0 \n
0 0 0 0 \n
0 0 0 0 \n

Output:

0 0 0 0 \n
1 1 1 1 \n
0 0 0 0 \n
0 0 0 0 \n

Comment: I don't see how `ans[1][1] = 2;` is supposed to produce your expected result  that doesn't even contain a `2`. I'm sure it will be easier to find the problem after you edit your post and include the entire code.

Comment: neither what you expect nor what you get makes sense.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: @RajatJaiswal do you print your 2D vector just after the assignment ? it is like the assignment is made in a function/method getting the vector by value (so the assignment has no effect outside) and the print elsewhere ?

Comment: What's `A` precisely, how is the output generated?

Comment: For above expected output A = 4

Comment: I am passing int A to a function and function returning 2D vector ans.

Comment: what that function does ? be more clear please, **show you code**

Comment: void prinVec2D(vector<vector<int> > &A){
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < A[i].size(); j++){
            cout << A[i][i] <<" ";
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }

}

vector<vector<int> > generateMatrix(int A){
    vector<vector<int> >  ans(A, vector<int>(A, 0));
    ans[1][1] = 1;
    return ans;
}



int main(){
    int A = 4;
    vector<vector<int> >  abc(A, vector<int>(A, 0));
    abc = generateMatrix(A);
    prinVec2D(abc);
    return 0;
}

Comment: so you print with `A[i][i]` rather than `A[i][j]`, an answer supposed that, set it as the best answer

Comment: I have edited the code section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
void prinVec2D(vector<vector<int> > &A)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < A[i].size(); j++){
      cout << A[i][i] <<" "; } cout <<endl;
  }
}
```

`cout << A[i][i]` must be replaced by `cout << A[i][j]`

The assignment works (of course) you just print wrongly your array

P.S. PonWer has a good idea imagining you print wrong your array

Answer (score 1):

Are you printing the array wrong?

like:

```
//pseudo code
for(int i = 0, i < maxI; i++)
{
   string temp = "";
   for(int j = 0, j < maxJ; j++)
   {
      temp += array[1][j]; //note [1][j]
   }
   temp += newLine;
   //print temp
}
```

Comment: I think this will lead to a compiler error string += int  is not defined... And newline isn't declared. Try to compile your code and its output before posting it.

Comment: I'm aware, I just wanted to show an example. That's why I wrote //pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

This code can do the job

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int A = 4;
    int ans[A][A] = {0};
    int i, j;
    cout << "Original Sequence\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < A; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < A; j++){
            cout << ans[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //Value allocation
    ans[1][1] = 1;
    cout << "\nModified Sequence\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < A; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < A; j++){
            cout << ans[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Original Sequence

0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

Modified Sequence

0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: This code is very platform specific and not really C++ acoording the standard. _tmain _TCHAR is microsoft stuff...

Comment: I edited the code so that it could be run in Dev c++ 5.6.3

Comment: conio.h is from dinosaur times

Answer (score 0):

Rather than indexing (and getting it wrong), you can just reference the elements of each vector

```
void printVec2D(const std::vector<std::vector<int> > & outer)
{
  for(auto & inner : outer)
  {
    for(auto & value : inner)
    {
      std::cout << value << " "; 
    } 
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```